# How can I get the width or height of an image field image into a twig template?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm using PhpStorm/xdebug/MAMP to look at the variable I want to access:

[image]

I have tried using the following to get at the data:

```
{% set image_width = content.field_image.0['#item'].values.width %}
```

and

```
{% set image_width = content.field_image.0['#item'].values.width.value %}
```

Neither of these lines produce any data.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: use hook_preprocess to create variable from the data. twig is not phptemplate engine, so you have to approach it differently than you'd do in d7.

Answer (score 7):

You can't access the array `values` because it is protected. But you don't need to, because you can get the properties from a field item directly:

```
{% set image_width = content.field_image.0['#item'].width %}
```

BTW the `content` variable is a render array with no fixed structure. The presence and position of `#item` changes dependent on the field formatter and other core, contrib or custom code.

So it's better to use the entity object, for example the paragraph entity in a paragraph template:

```
{% set image_width = paragraph.field_image.0.width %}
```

Comment: `{% set image_width = paragraph.field_image.0.width %}` works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If using Media (Drupal 8 or 9), here's an example on how to access the width of the image in a `node` template:

```
{% set image_width = node.field_image.entity.field_media_image.0.width %}
```

Please note that `field_image` is an Entity Reference to Media.